# Is the name Application reserved within Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Application model in a Rails 4 app.

It is giving me some strange errors in tests, including

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id=' for #<Application:0x007f851222d370>
```

and

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_id`
```

The model definitely has a `user_id` column. The migration looks like this:

```
....
t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
...
```

and inspecting `Application.column_names` in the console reveals it to be there.

application.rb and user.rb both have the relevant `belongs_to` and `has_many` calls defined.

I'm scratching my head and the only thing I can think of is that the term `Application` behaves strangely in Rails. Is this the case? Or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Have you prepared your test database and run migrations under `RAILS_ENV=test`?

Answer (score 2):

Rails does not declare `Application` in the "top-level namespace". There is `Rails.application` and rails generates a `ApplicationController` by default.

However you will need to often need to explicitly use `::Application` to avoid confusion with `Rails::Application`.

You don't even have to follow the Rails convention of extending `ApplicationController`.

However that said having a model named Application may be a bad idea since any poor sod who later has to work on your code will be very confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conflict with [Rails::Application](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html) class or its subclass, defined in config/application.rb, I believe.